# "I'm afraid to hear" and "I'm sorry to hear"

Tags: word-choice

> I'm sorry to hear that you won't be able to join the party.

In this sentence, I mean I can be upset, sad, disappointed instead of sorry.
In this case, is it possible to use *afraid* instead of sorry?
Can I use ”I'm afraid to hear” as ”I'm sorry to hear”?

Comment: No, they aren't the same. _I'm sorry to hear that `S`_ (where `S` is any sentence) is a conventional expression of condolence. And _I'm afraid that `S`_ is a conventional notification of bad news (_I'm afraid that your plane is delayed_). But that's only with tensed clauses, not infinitives. _I'm afraid to hear_ means that the speaker is afraid that the speaker will hear; it has nothing to do with the addressee.

Comment: That's what I confused. and now everxthing is clear.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler answered:

> No, they aren't the same. *I'm sorry to hear that `S`* (where `S` is any sentence) is a conventional expression of condolence. And *I'm afraid that `S`* is a conventional notification of bad news (*I'm afraid that your plane is delayed*). But that's only with tensed clauses, not infinitives. *I'm afraid to hear* means that the speaker is afraid that the speaker will hear; it has nothing to do with the addressee.

Comment: On the other hand, idiomatically one may say either "I'm afraid that I won't be able to join the party" or "I'm sorry to say that I won't be able to join the party" to convey essentially the same meaning: "I won't be joining the party, but I want to be polite about it."